# How do I import an Image from my src folder?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add an Image from my src folder, however it just displays a broken image on my website.

```html
<b-col class="details" md="8">
  <b-img src="../assets/southBank.png"></b-img>
</b-col>
```

I have been able to load the image via a card using this code

```html
<b-card :img-src="require('../assets/southBank.png')"
  style="max-height: 120px; width:550px; background-color: white; border:none; margin-top:-50px;">
</b-card>
```

However, I do not want to store it in a card.

Comment: use `require` with b-img, same as you do with b-card.  `<b-img :src="require('../assets/southBank.png')"></b-img>`.  Does that not work?

Comment: It does. I thought I tried that before, but I must have made an error. Thankyou

Comment: You might not have bound "src", e.g. `:src=` binds it to the require statement while `src=` does not